# GetAysncKeyState lowercase

Tags: vb.net, ascii, lowercase

I have declared the function

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Int32) As Integer
```

But a code such as

```
If GetAsyncKeyState(100) then
'do something
End
```

Will not work [It used to -.-]. However replacing 100 with 'Keys.D' will. Which leaves the problem of being limited to capital letters.

Is there a way to have Keys.a (as lowercase) or a way to use ascii codes in GetAsyncKeyState?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`100` (decimal) is [`VK_NUMPAD4 (0x64)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

If you want to detect lowercase you would need to examine the state of `VK_CAPITAL` & `VK_SHIFT`.

Comment: Ah, I thought I was supposed to put in an ascii value for the key. However, this should definitely help. TYVM =).

Comment: Yey, made a typo and got my answer. using Getasynckeystate(LCase(Keys.D)) Smaller case now works.